# Keyboard navigation in Safari gone after deployment to Google App Engine

Tags: vue.js, google-app-engine, accessibility, keyboard-navigation

I currently have a website built using Vue.js (2.x) and deployed using Google App Engine.

Upon testing the deployed application in Safari, I found that the accessibility feature ["'skip navigation' on :focus"](https://webaim.org/techniques/skipnav/) was not "supported" anymore (i.e. pressing `tab` only toggled browser's search bar, not links in webpage). In short, I wasn't able to use the `tab` key, `spacebar`, and `Shift` to navigate links and page content. However this was not an issue in Chrome.

App URL: https://ixplore-web.appspot.com/?

#### What I've tried:

**1.** I've went into the Google Developer documentation on [enabling accessibility features through `gcloud`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/enabling-accessibility-features), as well as the [App Engine FAQs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb) but they don't mention anything on covering for these accessibility issues. Although the first resource mentions how to configure accessibility for screen-readers, it doesn’t say anything about keyboard navigation.

**2.** I've checked out the [configuration files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/configuration-files) for deployment to Google App Engine such as `cloudbuild.yml` and `app.yml` and there doesn't seem to be anything on accessibility configuration (because why would deployment configuration have this?).

**3.** I have looked into the `.gitignore` file and there is nothing that ignores keyboard-based navigation. As a professional courtesy, I never disable/ignore anything related to web accessibility in web apps.

Has anyone comes across why an app deployed to App Engine and opened in Safari (13.1) doesn't "support" keyboard navigation?

Comment: Do you have a `.gcloudignore` file during your deploy to App Engine? If you do check if it's not ignoring any files that set up the Keyboard Navition. Since this is happening only in the deployed version, it could be what is causing the issue.

Comment: Oh I see - I don’t have that file actually. I wasn’t the one that deployed the app but I’ll will definitely check that out. Thanks! Also, who down-voted lol

Comment: If you don't have it, check your `.gitignore` also, it could be a ignoring in there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't anything related to .gitignore, or any files. In the Safari browser, tab-based navigation requires both '⌥ Option' + 'Tab' to navigate a webpage - see MDN Docs on keyboard accessibility (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/Accessibility).

The difference between the issue experienced in this post and the article is that by default, if you want to tab ALL "tab-able" items in a webpage, you **DO NOT** need to check the checkbox 'Press tab to highlight each element on webpage' under 'Safari > Preferences > Advanced'